# git push :: estimate approximate push size before pushing

Tags: git, version-control

Is there a way to guestimate the size of a **git push** before actually pushing?

My use case is that a large push size is a good indicator that I likely inadvertenly included some binaries in the staging area (since I usually add with **git add . -A**). I know I can do a **git add . -A -n** piped with a **grep** for the file extensions to watch out for, but a push dry run, so to speak, just to estimate the size would offer some additional reassurance.

Comment: I suggest a better approach would be to make sure you know what you are adding/committing each time. That way, you can be confident when you push that you are only pushing things you actually do want to push.

Comment: No, don't delete it. It will either remain as is, or get closed as a duplicate if there are enough votes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use just

```
 git add -A
```

you don't need the period.

You can also just go ahead and add and then commit everything. Now you can do

```
git log -1 --stat
```

this will show you what you are pushing. If you want to know the exact size, you can

```
git bundle create HEAD^ HEAD
```

and the file size it produces will be reflective of what will be transmitted if you were to push.

Now you can remove the files that you don't want and

```
git add -A && git commit --amend --no-edit
```

which will amend the last commit to include only what you wanted. No edit will reuse your original commit message.